# Is it possible to prevent a bean from being created?

Tags: spring-boot

I have an external dependency that instantiates a bean having a @Value property. Of course, if the property is not present, the application will crash (no default value).

Would it be possible that, under a certain profile, the bean is not created at all? Or inject at runtime the property to prevent the crash?

Comment: Would add the property to `application.properties` help?

Comment: Yes that would be the optimal way, problem is that we are dealing with a common library and that would force an update on several projects